is it ilegal your father to take your tech away if you bought it with your own money
hi i bought a new laptop to play games with my own money that i got for working on my grandmother's  garden.and my dad whanted to install parental control on it and alow me to play only when i study 3 math lessons every day (im 7 grade).and i refused to type in my pin and he took my laptop away.so is that ilegal?
(for me its not)

"If you live in their house, you must follow their rules"

Yes
Your father is responsible for your care and welfare, they have broad discretion to determine what that is and how best to achieve it.
They can impose rules and restrictions on the use of things their children own, including withholding access. So long as they give it back to you on your 18th birthday, they are not breaking any laws.
